# If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability then $X_n \Rightarrow X$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

> If $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability then $X_n \Rightarrow X$?

Below are my thoughts, then my questions - I am interested in your feedback on this argument.

Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability.  Does $X_n  \Rightarrow X$?

I know I can prove this if I can show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ almost surely implies that $X_n  \Rightarrow X$.  Here is my proof:

1) Show that weak convergence induces a metric space on the set of distribution functions.  This is a well-known fact - Levy metric will do.

2) Use Borel-Cantelli to show that for every subsequence $X_{n_k}$ there exists a further subsequence which converges to $X$ almost surely.

3) Then this further subsequence converges weakly to $X$ - but this is the fact I don't know how to prove, namely, that $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s, then $X_n \Rightarrow X$.

4) By 1 - I have shown that for every subsequence of $X_n$, there exists a further subsequence which converges to $X$ weakly. Since weak convergence induces a metric on the space of distribution functions, we can conclude that the original sequence converges to $X$ weakly.

Here are my questions:

> Q1: Is this a viable argument? If so, can you provide the details for 3).
>
> Q2: Is there a simple direct argument you can think of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a direct argument: first note that $|\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm iy}|\leqslant\min\{2,|x-y|\}$ for every real numbers $x$ and $y$ hence

> $$|\varphi_n(t)-\varphi(t)|\leqslant2P[|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon]+\varepsilon,
> $$

for every positive $\varepsilon$, where $\varphi_n(t)=E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX_n}]$ and $\varphi(t)=E[\mathrm e^{\mathrm itX}]$.

Now, assume that $X_n\to X$ in probability. Then, for every fixed positive $\varepsilon$, $P[|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon]\to0$, hence $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|\varphi_n(t)-\varphi(t)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. This is valid for every positive $\varepsilon$ hence $\varphi_n(t)\to\varphi(t)$. This convergence holds for every $t$ hence $X_n\to X$ in distribution.

Comment: This is good, and terse, but not too terse. I do wonder if this is as terse as you think of it at first.  I ended up producing two solutions here - one using generating functions and another using a direct argument and one of the equivalences in the Portmanteau lemma.